# Different results for same numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have simple formulas which multiplies numbers, but in different columns for the same multiplied numbers I got different results. I format all fields in numbers with two decimal places.

What is the problem?

Comment: You have some problem in your workbook that is not connected with multiplication operation but from this brief description your problem cannot be guessed.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem based on the information you have provided.

Comment: **Help us to help you; post more details.**

Comment: Simple multiplication of numbers that are in cells gives different results in different columns for the same numbers: =I10*I14*I16 gives different result from =J10*J14*J16 altought in cells are accordingly same numbers.

Comment: @MilosCitakovic The most likely explanation for the results you are seeing is that the numbers are not really the same.  How did you verify that they were, in fact, identical?  What is the actual contents of those cells?  In other words, what do you see when you select those cells and look at the formula bar?  Also, if you select those cells; place the cursor in the formula bar, and hit **F9**, what value shows up in the formula bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to Ron's comment and based on your comment that your fields are limited to two decimal places: It may be that the numbers in the different columns are not identical from the 3rd decimal place and on. Please provide the exact numbers you have - up to the maximum accuracy you have.